# Gradle/Maven - Error loading aar dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm publishing an aar file to an internal maven repo, but when I try to reference it like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example.android:example-api:0.3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':sdk-sample'.
> Artifact 'com.example.android:example-api:0.3-SNAPSHOT:example-api.jar' not found.
```

Which is confusing to me since I do not have a jar file that I've uploaded, but an aar.

The POM file that gradle generated and uploaded looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I reference it like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example.android:example-api:0.3-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```

Then it finds it successfully, but then the dependencies are not downloaded properly and i get a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime when I call the methods that use the dependencies.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitive property needs to be set to `true` on your dependency:

`compile ('com.example.android:example-api:0.3-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
    transitive = true
}`

It should probably be changed in Gradle to be `true` by default for `aar` dependencies (as it seems to be for `jar`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Appending "@aar" to the dependency fixed it for me. Compiling and running without problems now.